# Python, face_recognition convert string to array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string, numpy, face-recognition

I want to convert a variable to a string and then to an array that I can use to compare, but i dont know how to do that.
my code:

```
import face_recognition
import numpy as np

a = face_recognition.load_image_file('C:\\Users\zivsi\OneDrive\תמונות\סרט צילום\WIN_20191115_10_32_24_Pro.jpg')  # my picture 1
b = face_recognition.load_image_file('C:\\Users\zivsi\OneDrive\תמונות\סרט צילום\WIN_20191115_09_48_56_Pro.jpg')  # my picture 2
c = face_recognition.load_image_file(
'C:\\Users\zivsi\OneDrive\תמונות\סרט צילום\WIN_20191115_09_48_52_Pro.jpg')  # my picture 3
d = face_recognition.load_image_file('C:\\Users\zivsi\OneDrive\תמונות\סרט צילום\ziv sion.jpg')  # my picture 4
e = face_recognition.load_image_file(
'C:\\Users\zivsi\OneDrive\תמונות\סרט צילום\WIN_20191120_17_46_40_Pro.jpg')  # my picture 5
f = face_recognition.load_image_file(
'C:\\Users\zivsi\OneDrive\תמונות\סרט צילום\WIN_20191117_16_19_11_Pro.jpg')  # my picture 6

a = face_recognition.face_encodings(a)[0]
b = face_recognition.face_encodings(b)[0]
c = face_recognition.face_encodings(c)[0]
d = face_recognition.face_encodings(d)[0]
e = face_recognition.face_encodings(e)[0]
f = face_recognition.face_encodings(f)[0]
```

Here I tried to convert the variable to a string

```
str_variable = str(a)

array_variable = np.array(str_variable)

my_face = a, b, c, d, e, f, array_variable


while True:
    new = input('path: ')
    print('Recognizing...')
    unknown = face_recognition.load_image_file(new)
    unknown_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown)[0]
```

The program cannot use the variable:

```
    results = face_recognition.compare_faces(array_variable, unknown_encodings, tolerance=0.4)

    print(results)
    recognize_times = int(results.count(True))

    if (3 <= recognize_times):
        print('hello boss!')
        my_face = *my_face, unknown_encodings
```

please help me

The error shown:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/zivsi/PycharmProjects/AI/pytt.py", line 37, in <module>
    results = face_recognition.compare_faces(my_face, unknown_encodings, tolerance=0.4)
  File "C:\Users\zivsi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 222, in compare_faces
return list(face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding_to_check) <= tolerance)
  File "C:\Users\zivsi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 72, in face_distance
return np.linalg.norm(face_encodings - face_to_compare, axis=1)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (7,) (128,)
```

Comment: What does _The program cannot use the variable_ mean? Does it throw an error? It's difficult to tell what's happening since we can't run the program ourselves. Also, is this code sample as small as can be? Please see: [mcve], particularly the "minimal" part.

Comment: To understand my problem, I have to write all the code, and the code throws an error and says the variable type is not suitable for comparison

Comment: Could you share the full error message/traceback?

Answer (score -1):

- First of all, the `array_variable` should actually be a `list` of the known encodings and not a `numpy` array.
  Also you do not need `str`.
- Now, in your case, **if the input images i.e., `a,b,c,d,f,e` do NOT have the same dimensions, the error will persist. You can not compare images that have different sizes using this function. The reason is that the comparison is based on the distance and distance is defined on vectors of the same length.**

Here is a working simple example using the photos from https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/tree/master/examples:

```
import face_recognition
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from IPython.display import display

# Load a sample picture and learn how to recognize it.
obama_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("obama.jpg")
obama_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(obama_image)[0]

# Load a second sample picture and learn how to recognize it.
biden_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("biden.jpg")
biden_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(biden_image)[0]

array_variable = [obama_face_encoding,biden_face_encoding] # list of known encodings

# compare the list with the biden_face_encoding
results = face_recognition.compare_faces(array_variable, biden_face_encoding, tolerance=0.4)

print(results)
[False, True] # True means match, False mismatch

# False: coming from obama_face_encoding VS biden_face_encoding
# True: coming from biden_face_encoding VS biden_face_encoding
```

To run it go here: https://beta.deepnote.com/project/09705740-31c0-4d9a-8890-269ff1c3dfaf#

Documentation: https://face-recognition.readthedocs.io/en/latest/face_recognition.html

EDIT

To save the known encodings you can use `numpy.save`

```
np.save('encodings',biden_face_encoding) # save
load_again = np.load('encodings.npy') # load again
```

Comment: I want to know how I can make str to save the encodings in a text file and read the data in the next run from the file. So how can I convert the str to a type I can compare with?

Comment: you can directly save `obama_face_encoding` for example and load it

Comment: can you give an example? i dont understand. i want to know, how to save the list of the known encodings in text file and use the file to compare

Comment: Because I want to save face data to the next runs

Comment: It only works with saving one encodings variable I want to save a set of encodings variables (tuple of encodings)